# unknown runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

Dear All,I had published my company web site and when i tested it I had this error in status pare (unknown runtime error ,scriptresource.axd,code=0 ....) I had this error when I selected ddl.You can see this through this link on my website http://beta.elarabygroup.com/DealerList.aspx   . I hope any one help me

use this user to access page
 user: saad 
password:111

Comment: Please read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and rewrite your question.

Comment: you can access with this user saad password:111

Comment: -1, I'd love to help but with questions that are posted on this site. So please do the legwork and post code samples and error messages here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed the UpdatePanel from gridview and ddl and it worked well